# How to delete rows from H2 table with commited changes after each Junit test

Tags: sql, unit-testing, junit, h2, h2db

I am using H2 in-memory DB for unit testing interaction with a database.

I need to clean commited changes in @After so that tables stay but all rows get wiped away (thus I cannot just drop tables). My database also has many foreign keys which makes even wiping objects one by one cumbersome as I have to do it in certain order.

Is there any way to clean rows in a database without dropping tables and preferably without deleting objects one by one?

Comment: Would a combination of [truncate](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#truncate_table) and temporarily [disabling referential integrity](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#set_referential_integrity) do the trick?

Comment: @Avandeursen Oh yes it does, thank you! And I think that I can batch truncate the tables too.  What I needed is disabling referential integrity.

Comment: Another option might be to use @DirtiesContext with "after each test"

Comment: Glad it worked @AlexandraCohen. I have turned my comment into a real answer: Feel free to accept it if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clean the rows, you can use the H2 [TRUNCATE TABLE](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#truncate_table) data definition command.

You can temporarily disable checking foreign key constraints by using H2's [SET REFERENTIAL_INTEGRITY](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#set_referential_integrity).